# i change the sass code background color but why my background color not change?

Tags: laravel, sass

- hi i have this problem with my sass file i try to change background color in the Variables file but nothing change
- note the bootstrap apply with no problem, a success message popup also !!!
  sass code[image]

Comment: What does `npm run dev` do? Are you certain it compiles the Sass?

Comment: when i save the veriable.scss file and run ( npm run dev ) the app.css compile the new edit bg color on it ....... i check it

Comment: Use code block instead of image to display your code. Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

you need to be sure that your `scss` file compiled correctly. check output `css` file and compare them together.
if it is not compiled successfully you need to ask another question. but if it looks `OK` then you need to fully refresh your page (ctrl+f5). because of browser cache system.

it is a good practice to insert your css files in this way :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path2cssfile/your-css.css?update={{ filemtime('path2cssfile/your-css.css') }}" />
```

this will force browsers to reload the new compiled files.

Comment: thank you very very much its work i was use just the f5 in my keyboard, you are great

Comment: sir, i use the code you recomanded but an error popup i think i have mistake:                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css?update={{ filemtime('/css/app.css') }}" />

Comment: it is not very important ... but it should not make error if you fix the correct path to the `filemtime` function. it is a normal `php` function and it should work fine.